# UIImageViews turning black when scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I am using a subclass of UIImageView that I created, in which I set its tintColor to white:

```
class UIIconView : UIImageView {
    override init(image: UIImage?) {
        super.init(image: image)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.image = super.image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.tintColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

This is working properly, except when I put UIIconViews inside a cell of a UITableView. When I run the code and scroll through the UITableView, the white UIIconViews all turn black, like this:

[image: UIIconViews turning black when running the app]

So, does anyone know why this is happening?

PS: The original image I'm using for the icon is black, but I'm colouring them inside UIIconView's layoutSubviews(), if that helps.

Edit:

Ok, I stopped using the subclass of UIImageView. Here's my whole view controller code, for this table view screen:

```
class MessageCell: UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var icon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var msgTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var msgText: UILabel!
}

class MessagesListViewController: UITableViewController {

    let mockMessages = ["Msg1", "Msg2", "Msg3", "Msg4", "Msg5", "Msg6", "Msg7", "Msg8", "Msg9"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return mockMessages.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageCell", for: indexPath) as! MessageCell
        cell.msgTitle.text = mockMessages[indexPath.row]
        cell.msgText.text = mockMessages[indexPath.row]
        cell.icon.image = UIImage(named: "ic_email_48pt")
        cell.icon.tintColor = UIColor.white
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your `cellForRow` method

Comment: I wouldn't recommend subclassing `UIImageView` for this. Move out the code from `layoutSubviews()` to the `cellForRowAt` method of your table view's delegate.

Comment: `layoutSubviews` should only be used to update the frames of subviews of the view. It should never be used for anything else. The code you currently have in `layoutSubviews` should only be called once in the `init` methods. And always call `super.layoutSubviews` when you override it.

Comment: @the4kman alright, edited my question with more info.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the info. I'm no longer subclassing UIImageView to change its color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @the4kman and @rmaddy recommended, I'm no longer subclassing UIImageView to change its color. Instead, I'm doing that inside the cellForRowAt method of my view controller and now it works.